# Dispatch event handler in separate threads in Java NIO Reactor Pattern

Tags: java, selector, nio, reactor

I'm writing a simple Server application with java NIO using the `Reactor Pattern`. To my understanding, the `Reactor` class is responsible for collecting  `Events` (such as : OP_ACCEPT,OP_READ,OP_WRITE).

The relative `EventHandler` would be responsible for the specific task. Hence handlers should be able run in separate threads asynchronously.

here is the code :[image]

When I run this, it shows some problems, the while loop keeps running, and the `Selector` keeps return readyOps set of (1,4,16). I guess it's because the `AcceptHanndler` didn't handle the `OP_ACCEPT` in a blocking manner. Hence even when the key is removed from the iterator, after a `select()` call, it would show up again.

Can't I run the eventHander as a runnable in a separate thread?

The concept of `edge-triggered` and `level-triggered` models comes to my mind. Does the reason is because the selector is runing in `level-triggered` model ?

Comment: The whole point of Selectors is hat you *don't* have to use separate threads.

Comment: The point of `Selector` is to manage multiple socket in one thread , i did not use thread per client  .

Comment: You're doing far worse than that. You're basically using a thread *per selector event*. You should execute the handlers in the current thread, and only use auxiliary threads for long-running events like database accesses, *after* you have completed the accept or the read or wherever the event was in the current thread. Your basic model is broken..

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Selector is level-triggered. Standard workflow in your case would be following: after you detect that channel is acceptable, cancel that key from Selector and only after that pass that key to event handler thread. Event handler thread would complete accept and 1) register server socket once again for OP_ACCEPT; 2) register accepted client socket for OP_READ and/or OP_WRITE depending on protocol you want to implement. Alternatively, you may complete accept in main thread (for performance reasons, if there is a swarm of connecting clients).

Actually, differentiating threads by operation type is not scalable and may have poor performance in SMP systems because of poor data locality. It is better to lock each client socket to single thread. High performance java servers are usually implemented by having one thread exclusively for accepting (only single ServerSocket is registered there) and N worker threads for working with client sockets. Accepting thread works in a loop:

1. blocks in select() until new client arrives
2. completes accept
3. chooses least loaded worker thread and transfers ownership of newly accepted client socket there

Each worker thread has its own Selector and set of client sockets and is responsible for reading/writing these sockets.

Comment: tks for your reply :D .  If the Selector is `level-triggered` , then i have to complete all the event-handlers before next `select()` . so the this thread model i choose will never work ... actually what i thought is not to hold every `event` with a thread , i could use AIO with every read/write operation , so it won't hold the thread , and the `Selector` would take one thread so it would focus on `event collect` ...